# How to make a Jpql query work in Spring Jpa Repository with Optional return?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jpql

I am using Jpql queries in my JpaRepository. The problem is that every time I call a method with an optional return I get this error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast
> to class com.netpos.pagvendas.campaignuser.entity.CampaignUser
> ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap';
> com.netpos.pagvendas.campaignuser.entity.CampaignUser is in unnamed
> module of loader
> org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader
> @1c069e07)

This is my Repository class, and the method that I am trying to use is :

`findByCampaignCodUniqueCampaignAndCodTenant(String codUniqueCampaign, String codTenant)`

```
@Repository
public interface CampaignUserRepository extends JpaRepository<CampaignUser, CampaignUserPk> {

    @Query("SELECT campaignUser, campaignUser.campaign from CampaignUser campaignUser " +
            "where campaignUser.codTenant = :codTenant " +
            "and campaignUser.flgFinished = false " +
            "and :now >= campaignUser.campaign.datStart and :now <= campaignUser.campaign.datEnd " +
            "order by campaignUser.datCreation ASC")
    List<CampaignUser> findActiveCampaign(String codTenant, ZonedDateTime now);

    @Query("SELECT campaignUser, campaignUser.campaign from CampaignUser campaignUser " +
            "where campaignUser.idtCampaign = :idtCampaign ")
    List<CampaignUser> findByIdtCampaign(long idtCampaign);

    @Query("SELECT campaignUser, campaignUser.campaign from CampaignUser campaignUser " +
            "where campaignUser.campaign.codUniqueCampaign = :codUniqueCampaign " +
            "and campaignUser.codTenant = :codTenant")
    Optional<CampaignUser> findByCampaignCodUniqueCampaignAndCodTenant(String codUniqueCampaign, String codTenant);
}
```

Is it possible to use Optional with Jpql queries in JpaRepository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are there two objects in the selection? To load `CampaignUser` with `Campaign` by a single query you have to start the query this way

`select campaignUser from  CampaignUser campaignUser join fetch campaignUser.campaign campaign`

or even

`from CampaignUser campaignUser join fetch campaignUser.campaign campaign`

```
 @Query("SELECT campaignUser from CampaignUser campaignUser join fetch campaignUser.campaign campaign " +
                "where campaign.codUniqueCampaign = :codUniqueCampaign " +
                "and campaignUser.codTenant = :codTenant")
 Optional<CampaignUser> findByCampaignCodUniqueCampaignAndCodTenant(String codUniqueCampaign, String codTenant);
```

Comment: If I do this way, the code makes a query to get CampaignUser and other query to get Campaign. I don't know why, but even if I put FetchType.Eager, it didn't work.

Comment: No need to use `FetchType.Eager`. To load `CampaignUser` with `Campaign` by a single query you should use `join fetch`. I have edited the answer